# Commenting system for WordPress

Tags: comments

Hi I am thinking of changing from the default WordPress commenting system to Disqus or LiveFyre. What are the biggest advantages of such a change, and maybe possible pitfalls I should look out for. Thanks.

Comment: Chose LiveFyre in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Disqus you are in a way giving away the control to that company. The module is indeed very nicely built, you can access Disqus admin section from within your WP admin panel, but like I said; you are handing over the "root control" to Disqus.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more your list: [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/). Check [this link](http://www.kidnapcustomers.com/how-to-make-a-website/intensedebate-vs-disqus-vs-livefyre-vs-commentluv/) for something similar.
The pitfall I faced when I used ID was incorrect comments sync.

Comment: Is there still a problem with incorrect comments sync?

Comment: Not sure, I used it almost 7 months back.